# Algorithm for random numbers generation

Tags: node.js, algorithm

I don't know which algorithm should I use. If it's necessary the platform is `Node.js`.

```
Volume = 100; Range = 5...15; N = 10.
```

I need to generate `N` numbers from Range that in sum will give Volume. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: you need possible `numbers` from `Range`?

Comment: With or without repetition?

Comment: @Dave it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick, naive implementation.

There might be a numerical trick that allows making this faster, but this works. :)

Note that it's of course possible to pass in a combination of parameters that makes this function never complete, but for `total = 100, min = 5, max = 15, n = 10` it does find solutions, e.g.

```
[ 14, 5, 11, 6, 10, 13, 9, 13, 14, 5 ]
[ 15, 13, 14, 10, 9, 8, 10, 8, 6, 7 ]
[ 8, 11, 11, 9, 12, 15, 5, 9, 6, 14 ]
[ 9, 12, 11, 6, 14, 12, 10, 7, 11, 8 ]
[ 9, 8, 9, 10, 11, 10, 12, 7, 14, 10 ]
[ 9, 9, 5, 14, 10, 13, 11, 13, 9, 7 ]
```

---

```
function generateNumbers(total, min, max, n) {
  while (true) {
    const numbers = [];
    let sum = 0;
    while (true) {
      let num;
      if (numbers.length === n - 1) {
        // Fill in the last number with the remainder to satisfy the problem
        num = total - sum;
        if (num < min || num === 0 || num > max) {
          // Out of bounds, this solution is invalid
          break; // Try again.
        }
      } else {
        num = Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min));
      }
      numbers.push(num);
      sum += num;
      if (numbers.length === n && sum === total) {
        // Solution found.
        return numbers;
      }
      if (sum > total) {
        // Overshot, retry.
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(generateNumbers(100, 5, 15, 10));
```

Comment: Yeah, I have only this idea in my mind. I'm afraid of large amount of time, that might be used for generating. Not in this example, of course. However, thanks for help!